# If $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$ when $R$ is not commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was dealing with the following problem (Hungerford IV Ex4.5):

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity; then there is a *ring* isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R^{op}$ where $\mathrm{Hom}_R$ denotes left $R$-module homomorphisms. In particular, if $R$ is commutative, then there is a ring isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$.

Now if we have shown that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R^{op}$ and $R$ is commutative, then $R^{op}\cong R$ and the conclusion follows naturally. However I think that the condition $R$ is commutative may be omitted. Here is the reason:

> We prove that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$. Suppose $a\in R$. Then we define $\psi_a:r\mapsto ra$. It is easy to verify that $\psi_a\in\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)$. Let $f:\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\ni\psi_a\mapsto a\in R$. Then $f$ is both injective and surjective, and hence an isomorphism. Therefore $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$.

In may (sketch of) proof no commutativity is used (or I was not aware of). So does $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R$ hold for noncommutative rings or I made a mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the multiplication of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R)$?

Comment: The multiplication of $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)$ is the composition of functions.

Comment: What is $f\circ g$?  Is it first doing $g$ and then $f$, or first doing $f$ and then $g$?

Comment: Suppose $f,g\in\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)$, then the multiplication between $f$ and $g$ is denoted to be $f\circ g$, i.e. $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))$.

Comment: Ok, then in the association $\psi_a\mapsto a$, $\psi_a \circ \psi_b$ maps to $ba$ so it's an order-reversing map.  An order reversing map is an isomorphism from $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R,R)$ to $R^{\operatorname{op}}$.

Comment: You are right. I was being too careless when dealing with the composition. Thank you.

Comment: In general $R$ need not be isomorphic to $R^{op}$.

Comment: @Chad This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.